# Drawing a canvas into a bitmap

Tags: android, canvas, bitmap

I want to save the `canvas` in a `bitmap` so I could draw that bitmap on other canvas.
the problem is that i dont know how to set the bitmap size to be the whole canvas(not the whole screen, the size of a layout of mine)

how do i set the `bitmap` size? and then how do i save my `canvas` on it?

Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0):

I use this procedure and you can set the width and height of your view instead of bitmap.getWidth() and bitmap.getHeight() as here I am overriding a bitmap

```
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final int color = 0xff424242;
        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);
        final float roundPx = pixels;

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        paint.setColor(color);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, roundPx, roundPx, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);
```

Hope this helps :)